# get worldOrientation as the target of other objects

Tags: world

If I have an object in my game, and I want other objects moves to the same orientation. what should i do?

I want it moves slowly to the orientation, but not the get the position without a time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear if you mean the object's position (worldPosition) or orientation (worldOrientation).

Either way you can get smooth change of orientation by using bge game object function alignAxisToVector(vect, axis, factor). As vector, input the other gameobject's corresponding vector (like positive X-axis) and as the factor using a small number like 0.1 to make the transition smooth. https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=alignaxis#bge.types.KX_GameObject.alignAxisToVect

You can get smooth change of position by first getting the delta vector between the objects and then adding only a small factor like 0.05 of it to your objects position every frame.